# Linux directory is stuck in read-only

Tags: linux, angularjs, permissions, yeoman, readonly

I' having issues with using Yeoman with Angular. It was working fine until I used

> grunt serve

To start a server for the project I was creating.

However, "grunt serve" returned

> Error: Unable to create git_template directory: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings

and then it gave me

> Warning: EROFS, read-only file system 'app/index.html' Use --force to continue

I then used

> grunt serve --force

to solve this issue, and then it hit me.

**My entire local file had become Read-only.**

I tried "yo doctor" (that is the Yeoman way to find issues) and that does not even work anymore. It gave me this error:

```
colin@Studio-XPS-1640:~/Desktop/ang-news$ yo doctor

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:66
                throw err;
                      ^
Error: EROFS, read-only file system '/home/colin/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:410:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:956:15)
    at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:56:8)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:19:11)
    at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/insight.js:23:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:23:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
```

I tried using chod and chown, but to no avail. Here's an example of what I tried

> sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/ -R -w

I think all I did was mess up permissions, and now I cannot even use Yeoman any longer because all of those files are read-only.

**EDIT**

Turns out that my entire system is read-only. How do I solve that? I tried to pull some content via the cmd, and it gave me

"OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/colin/startup-001'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your system has put the filesystem in read only mode. That happens in a number of cases. You should check dmesg for errors, and possibly reboot and do a filesystem check.

Also, it might not be a good idea to give full rights to all users in the common folders, like /usr/local.

Comment: Thanks! It's amazing what a simple re-boot can do.